# Exporting Pandas output for multiple CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I have many CSV files under subdirectories in one folder. They all contain tweets and other metadata. I am interested in removing most of these metadata and keeping the tweets themselves and their time. I used glob to read the files, and the removing part seems to be working fine. However, I am not sure how to save the output so that **all** files are saved and with their original file name.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'D:\tweets'
myfiles= glob.glob(r'D:\tweets\**\*.csv', recursive=True)
for f in myfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
df = df.drop(["name", "id","conversation_id","created_at","date"], axis=1)
df = df[df["language"].str.contains("bn|ca|ckbu|id||zh")==False]
df.to_csv("output_filename.csv", index=False, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Are their Indenting Problems in your question? If not, there isn't only the last file in D:\tweets is getting converted back into a csv.

Comment: The only indentation I have is in the sixth line (df = pd.read_csv(f))

Comment: As you are processing each from the list `myfiles`, your code needs to be part of the for loop.  i don't think you would need to overwrite the original file, then something like will help `df.to_csv(os.path.splitext(f)[0]+"_transformed.csv")`

Comment: @simpleApp This worked like magic!!! Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If you do it this way, it will overwrite the same file:

```
for f in myfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df.drop(["name", "id","conversation_id","created_at","date"], axis=1)
    df = df[df["language"].str.contains("bn|ca|ckbu|id||zh")==False]
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, encoding='utf8')
```